# jar as daemon on ubuntu uses 100% cpu

Tags: java, ubuntu, jar, cpu, daemon

I start a jar file as a daemon. Its a simple scanning app that runs a thread that scans a folder. I use sleep 60000ms so if I run the app on my mac the cpu usage is near to 0%.

If I run the jar as a daemon on my 32b Ubuntu server it consumes 100% cpu in idle (eg. no files in the folder it scans).

```
sudo start-stop-daemon --start --quiet -b -m --pidfile /var/run/filecom.pid --exec /usr/bin/java -- -Xms128m -Xmx128m -jar /apps/FileCom/filecom.jar
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

**EDIT**

I do a Thread.sleep(60000). When I dont run it as daemon it doesn't consume that much cpu. My guess is that it has something to do with my daemon stuff.

```
public void run() 
{
    //Create our root folder (folder to scan)
    File root = new File(rootFolder);

    //Start the loop
    while(true)
    {
        //List all files in the root folder
        File[] filesInRoot = root.listFiles();

        Arrays.sort( filesInRoot, new Comparator<Object>()
        {
            public int compare(Object o1, Object o2) 
            {
                if (((File)o1).lastModified() < ((File)o2).lastModified()) 
                {
                    return -1;
                } 
                else if (((File)o1).lastModified() > ((File)o2).lastModified()) 
                {
                    return +1;
                } 
                else 
                {
                    return 0;
                }
                }

        }); 

        //If there are no files in the target folder then move the first file in the array
        if(filesInRoot.length>0)
        {

            LogUtil.write(">> Finds file in in queue: " + filesInRoot[0].getName());

            //Check that the file has been written, EOF
            if(checkEOF(filesInRoot[0]))
            {
                LogUtil.write(">> File is complete, preparing to move");
                    //Rename the file using time and date - to make it unique
                    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
                    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd");
                    Long time = cal.getTimeInMillis();
                    String fileprefix = sdf.format(cal.getTime())+time.toString();
                    String processFileName = fileprefix+"_"+filesInRoot[0].getName();
                    //Move the file and rename it
                    File processFile = new File(processFolder, processFileName);

                    boolean success = filesInRoot[0].renameTo(processFile);

                    if (success) 
                    {
                        LogUtil.write(">> Success: File was moved to "+processFolder);
                        LogUtil.write(">> Processing....");


                        try 
                        {   
                            //Do stuff

                         } 
                         catch (Exception e) //Handles all errors
                         {

                            LogUtil.write(e);
                         }
                         finally
                         {
                            //Create backup of the infile (outfile is bupped in writeResponseObject)
                            File bupInFile = new File(bupFolder+"/in", processFileName);
                            processFile.renameTo(bupInFile);
                            LogUtil.write(">> inFile backed up: "+bupInFile.getAbsolutePath());
                         }
                     }   
                     else
                     {
                         LogUtil.write(">> Failure: File could not be moved ");
                     }
                }
            else
            {
                LogUtil.write(">> Failure: file is still beeing written...");
            }
                try 
                {
                    Thread.sleep(FileCom.PROSchedule);
                } 
                catch (InterruptedException ie) 
                {
                    ie.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the code, the braces don't quite match up and it looks like that you're only sleeping if there are files in the folder.

Try your daemon code with a file in the folder and see whether CPU usage still spikes.

Also, it helps if you use proper indentation with your code.

Comment: I drive myself bananas! How could I miss that?! The sleep was not in the root of the while loop just as you said! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

First off, it would help if you post the code that's actually doing the folder scanning. These API have very different implementations in the VM for each OS, so it's not unusual that you're experiencing different behaviours.

Secondly, is your code a continious while loop without any thread sleeping done in Java? If so this is not really good. You should give your code sleep/yield times, and you should do it in Java rather then in the command line, this way the VM will properly adress the OS scheduler for threads scheduling etc.

At any rate, the reason why you get better CPU usage on OS/X might have to do with the aggressive preemptiveness of that OS, which doesn't let anything that's not doing anything "useful" hog the CPU.

Answer (score 0):

--- Edited after you posted the code ---

Your problem is in this line block of code

```
    if(filesInRoot.length>0) {
            ... a lot of stuff goes here ...
            try 
            {
                Thread.sleep(FileCom.PROSchedule);
            } 
            catch (InterruptedException ie) 
            {
                ie.printStackTrace();
            }
    }
```

So if `filesInRoot.length == 0` you don't sleep.

You need to rearrange the code like so

```
    if (filesInRoot.length > 0) {
      ... a lot of stuff goes here ...
    }

    try {
      Thread.sleep(FileCom.PROSchedule);
    } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
      ie.printStackTrace();
    }
```

--- Original post follows ---

Perhaps you make an assumption that is valid for MacOSX but fails in Ubuntu.  Who knows, you might be at 100% CPU because you never enter the block of code where your `sleep(...)` resides.

Source code is ideal for having relevant discussions on such topics.  Without it, everything becomes a guessing game.  A lot of us are good at guessing, but we don't like to do it.  It's just too error prone and we like to maintain reputations of at least attempting to provide useful help.

Try putting the relevant code in a very small example program.  At best, you'll discover and solve your own problem before finishing the example.  At worst, you'll have a working example of the differing behavior which will allow others to provide you with meaningful relevant solutions.